# Taking limits in stochastic partial differential initial value problems

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, limits-and-convergence, stochastic-differential-equations

*Background:* **A (stochastic) Cauchy problem** I am interested in looks like this:

$$ 
(1) \hspace{0.5cm} \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+A(u) \cdot \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} =\nu \cdot \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} + \epsilon \cdot f(u) \cdot \frac{d B}{d t}, $$
$$(2) \hspace{0.5cm} u(x,0)=u_0(x),
$$

where $x \in \mathcal{O} \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $t \in [0,T]$, $u(x,t) \in  \mathbb{R}^n, n \geq 1$ and $B$ is Brownian motion (so $\frac{d B}{d t}$ represents a white noise stochastic process).

Let's suppose that the problem $(1)-(2)$ has some solution (e.g. in the weak or strong PDE sense or measure-valued etc.). And let's note that the problem $(1)-(2)$ is just a special case of the **more general problem:**

$$ 
(3) \hspace{0.5cm}\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}+A(u) \cdot \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\sum_{i=1}^{m}\nu_i \cdot g_i + \sum_{i=1}^{k}\epsilon_i \cdot s_i,$$
$$(4) \hspace{0.5cm} u(x,0)=u_0(x),
$$

where the *first terms* on the right hand side of the $(3)$ represent some deterministic terms (which can but don't have to depend on the derivatives of $u$ as in the $(1)$),

and the *second terms* on the right hand side of the $(3)$ represent some stochastic processes (not necessarily the white noise; and they can but don't have to depend of the variable $u$).

**My question:**

Let's say that the problem $(1)-(2)$  is some approximation problem of some other problem, and that in order to go back to the original problem we need to let some terms on the right hand side of $(1)$ to zero. My question is what conditions need to be satisfied in order to pass to the limit $\nu \rightarrow 0$ or $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ or **both** together in the problem $(1)-(2)$?. Similar question goes for the problem $(3)-(4)$ respectively.

Examples where something like this is done would be nice. Some theory concerning this would be great. And a good reference in the literature would be amazing. Thanks in advance.